# Terminate Google Speech-To-Text streamingRecoginze() RPC call from client side(Node.js SDK)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

Is there a way to terminate Google STT streamingRecognize() RPC call from client side? I am using [NodeJS library](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech) and [node-audiorecorder](https://github.com/RedKenrok/node-audiorecorder) to achive streaming from the Mic.

Also, how do you handle the network unavailability when google client disconnected?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question, but according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#performing_streaming_speech_recognition_on_an_audio_stream) example, you would just use `ctrl-c` to terminate the process, or audioRecorder.Stop() from node-audiorecorder.

Comment: Yes. `audioRecorder.stop()` will close the upstream from the client. But by doing that does the RPC call get terminated too? `ctrl-c` is not an option for me in this use-case of mine. Sorry if my question is silly. I am not familiar with gRPC.

Comment: Yes when the client closes the input stream the RPC is terminated.

Comment: Thank you @dhauptman for your help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To terminate the the RPC call from the client side you can use `audioRecorder.stop()` from the node-audiorecorder.

You can get more information on how gRPC works in the [gRPC concepts](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts.html#overview)  documentation.

On how to handle network failures and other errors you can take a look at [this](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/error.html#network-failures). [Here](http://avi.im/grpc-errors/) you can find some examples.

Comment: Thank you for your help!